# Misplaced \noalign. \captionsetup ->\noalign when using \captionsetup inside memoir \legend command

Tags: errors, captions, memoir, multirow, legend

I am trying to set up the memoir `\legend` command to use colon `:` as the caption separation label, while using dash `--` on all other captions. The problem happens when I use my custom memoir `\legend` command inside a `\multicolumn` environment.

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\captionsetup ->\noalign
                         \bgroup \@ifstar \@captionsetup \@captionsetup
l.36 \end{tabularx}
```

On the next image, you can see the wrong `\legend` in red. This is the partial PDF generated with the `\legend` command throwing the error `\noalign. \captionsetup ->\noalign`. On the other two green texts, are the labels correctly assigned for caption and legend:

[image]

If you remove the line `\captionsetup{labelsep=colon}`, everything compiles fine, except that all `\legends` are going to use the default dash `--` instead of the colon `:`

How can I make the first `\legend` caption inside `\multicolumn` use colon `:` instead of dash `--`?

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\RequirePackage{ltablex}\keepXColumns

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\legend}[2][var]{%
  \M@gettitle{#2}%
  \memlegendinfo{#2}%
  \par
  \begingroup
     \@parboxrestore
     \if@minipage
       \@setminipage
     \fi
     \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{4pt}
     \captiondelim{:}
     \captionsetup{labelsep=colon}
     \@makecaption{ #1}{\ignorespaces #2}\par
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{barr}{~\textendash~}
\captionsetup{format=hang,labelseparator=barr,}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\RaggedRight}p{3cm}|>{\arraybackslash}X}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}{\legend{O autor}}
\endlastfoot
    Cor                          & Branco \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Something}
\begin{tabular}{p{2.6cm}p{6.0cm}}
    Meta & Paradigma \\
\end{tabular}
\legend{Something}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems quite complicated and hacked together. Can you take a step back and describe what you actually want to achieve, output-wise? There is probably a better way to achieve this ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multicolumn doesn't like the \captionsetup command, but you can set the separator directly:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\RequirePackage{ltablex}\keepXColumns

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\legend}[2][var]{%
  \M@gettitle{#2}%
  \memlegendinfo{#2}%
  \par
  \begingroup
     \@parboxrestore
     \if@minipage
       \@setminipage
     \fi
     \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{4pt}%
     \caption@setlabelseparator{colon}%
     \@makecaption{#1}{\ignorespaces #2}\par
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{barr}{~\textendash~}
\captionsetup{format=hang,labelseparator=barr,}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\RaggedRight}p{3cm}|>{\arraybackslash}X}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}{\legend{O autor}}
\endlastfoot
    Cor                          & Branco \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Something}
\begin{tabular}{p{2.6cm}p{6.0cm}}
    Meta & Paradigma \\
\end{tabular}
\legend{Something}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Life savior! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Crosslink: this breaks in newer version of the package (OP 's new question) [errors - How to fix Undefined control sequence \caption@setlabelseparator with TexLive 2022? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639440/how-to-fix-undefined-control-sequence-captionsetlabelseparator-with-texlive-20)