# How to fix Undefined control sequence \caption@setlabelseparator with TexLive 2022?

Tags: errors, captions, memoir, multirow, legend

I am trying to use again the answer from this question of mine from 2019 ([Misplaced \noalign. \captionsetup ->\noalign when using \captionsetup inside memoir \legend command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515460/misplaced-noalign-captionsetup-noalign-when-using-captionsetup-inside-mem)) with Tex Live 2022, but the code from the answer is not compiling anymore:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\RequirePackage{ltablex}\keepXColumns

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\legend}[2][var]{%
  \M@gettitle{#2}%
  \memlegendinfo{#2}%
  \par
  \begingroup
     \@parboxrestore
     \if@minipage
       \@setminipage
     \fi
     \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{4pt}%
     \caption@setlabelseparator{colon}%
     \@makecaption{#1}{\ignorespaces #2}\par
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{barr}{~\textendash~}
\captionsetup{format=hang,labelseparator=barr,}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\RaggedRight}p{3cm}|>{\arraybackslash}X}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}{\legend{O autor}}
\endlastfoot
    Cor                          & Branco \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Something}
\begin{tabular}{p{2.6cm}p{6.0cm}}
    Meta & Paradigma \\
\end{tabular}
\legend{Something}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It says:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/ltcaption.sty)
./main.tex:34: Undefined control sequence.
\\legend ...skip }{4pt}\caption@setlabelseparator 
                                                  {colon}\@makecaption {#1}{...
l.34 \end{tabularx}
                   
?
```

In my final document was also using `\captiondelim{:~}` together with `\caption@setlabelseparator{colon}`, and now only using `\captiondelim{:~}` the error becomes:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/ltcaption.sty)
./main.tex:34: Misplaced \noalign.
\captionsetup ->\noalign 
                         \bgroup \@ifstar \@captionsetup \@captionsetup 
l.34 \end{tabularx}
                   
?
```

If I remove both `\caption@setlabelseparator{colon}` and `\captiondelim{:~}` the PDF compiles fine, but it uses dashes everywhere, and for my template, it would be required for it to use colon `:` instead of dashes `--` for the `\legend` command:

[image]

How can I keep using the `\captiondelim{:~}` or `\caption@setlabelseparator{colon}` after this updating to TexLive 2022?

Answer (score 0):

On the commit https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/commit/a9a968f976865fd617f4f431e5b4b2ebdd0b0882?page=4#791450f831b92438f900ff0b01fbce50725be9f7_680_654 while changing the file `caption3.sty`, the command `\caption@setlabelseparator{colon}` was renamed to `\caption@set{labelseparator}{colon}`, so with this I fixed the code for old and new versions of the package:

```
     \ifdefined\caption@setlabelseparator
       \caption@setlabelseparator{colon}%
     \else
       \caption@set{labelseparator}{colon}%
     \fi
```